# Paypal useraction=commit is not giving me the buy button

Tags: symfony, paypal, payum

I am using the payum bundle in symfony2, both latest versions, and the Paypal sandbox. Everything seems to be working fine, except I can't get the Continue button to switch to Pay Now in Paypal. I've set the useraction=commit part of the url in payum config, and checked the resulting url. It looks like this

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-87614818UL1184502&USERACTION=commit
```

I've tried changing useraction to lower case, and moving it to before the token (you can tell I've run out of ideas) but nothing works.

Does anyone have any ideas what I can try next?

Here is the SEC request

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: "GBP"
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: "10.80"
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC: "credits"
NOSHIPPING: 1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: "Sale"
EMAIL: "dave@xxxxx"
AUTHORIZE_TOKEN_USERACTION: "commit"
INVNUM: 122
RETURNURL: "http:\/\/192.168.2.10\/payment\/capture\/VL_5r_N-f9RAljt_b5eq928Gfwm3AtywOaUJMmWeOUw"
CANCELURL: "http:\/\/192.168.2.10\/payment\/capture\/VL_5r_N-f9RAljt_b5eq928Gfwm3AtywOaUJMmWeOUw"
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL: "http:\/\/192.168.2.10\/payment\/notify\/Mx1iGL9qDoRdPINl_7BYGu4Yyt9KKu3f-FblqW72gEE"
```

many thanks
Dave

Comment: There must be something unique about the SEC request causing it to not allow that.  I created a token and made my redirect URL look just like yours and I'm getting the Pay button just fine.  Can you post a sample of your entire SEC request?

Comment: Thanks, I added the request to the question. I have seen that manual, thanks, that's what I used to set it in payum config.

Comment: This manual could be helpful: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/paypal/express-checkout/authorize-token-custom-query-parameters.md

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured this out. It was indeed that USERACTION needs to be in lower case. I've asked the Payum team to fix this.